# In Java EE, can spaces and line breaks be placed before a method name?

Tags: java, methods, between, spaces

I never coded like that, but the code I am reading has a lot of spaces and cr before the method name. For example, Logger.instance()

```
            .debug("(actionCodeRange(3,3) && priorStatusCodeRange(2,7)):"
```

This looks really wrong to me.

Answer (score 2):

Java allows whitespaces (spaces, tabs, line breaks) between object names and their method calls.

This will be legal:

```java
logger  .  debug("some message");
```

And even this would be:

```java
logger
.
debug("some message");
```

I agree this isn't the most sightly code in the world, but it's perfectly legal.

Using line breaks like this usually comes in handy when you want to chain a bunch of method calls:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.append("This is the first string to be appended")
  .append("And this is the second")
  .append("etc,")
  .append("etc,")
  .append("etc.")
```

Comment: I'd also add, that it's not about `JavaEE`. Java EE is just an extension enterprise platform, which has a base (which you're asking for) semantics of core `Java SE`.

Comment: Mureinik, You clearly answered my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Whitespace between tokens is not significant. That is, you can't put spaces in identifiers, numbers, keywords (like **int**) or in multi-character operators (like **+=**).  And spaces are not ignored in strings.  But otherwise, insert them where you want.

`2+2` is the same as `2    +     2` is the same as

```
      2
      +
      2
```

Likewise you can put spaces around the `.` separator.

Comment: The '.' separator was where I had my doubts.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Whitespaces between tokens are insignificant to the compiler.

As always with this kind of questions, the answer lies in the [Java Language Specification, § 2.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.2):

> These input elements, **with white space (§3.6) and comments (§3.7) discarded**, form the terminal symbols for the syntactic grammar for the Java programming language and are called tokens (§3.5).

(Emphasis mine.)

---

Whitepace is significant

- within a string literal

  ```
  "Hello World!"
  ```
- within a character literal

  ```
  ' '
  ```
- as separator between tokens

  ```
  boolean interface; // not valid, 'interface' is a keyword
  int erface; // valid, the space makes sure that the compiler
  // produces two tokens instead of one: the keyword 'int' and the
  // identifier 'erface'
  ```

Comment: Thank you for spending the time for reply.